# context must be a dict rather than set

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have started learning Django and I have got stuck on this point. I am facing this problem and I am at loss at what is the issue. Even though the view on which this issue occurs(which is UserFormView) is returning a dictionary.

Error Log:

```
TypeError at /music/register/

context must be a dict rather than set.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/register/
Django Version:     2.1.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

context must be a dict rather than set.

Exception Location:     E:\Python Projects\Django_Enviroment\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py in make_context, line 270
Python Executable:  E:\Python Projects\Django_Enviroment\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.3
Python Path:    

['E:\\Python '
 'Projects\\Django_Enviroment\\Django_Projects\\Test_Projects\\ist_site',
 'E:\\Python Projects\\Django_Enviroment\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'E:\\Python 3.6.3\\DLLs',
 'E:\\Python 3.6.3\\lib',
 'E:\\Python 3.6.3',
 'E:\\Python Projects\\Django_Enviroment',
 'E:\\Python Projects\\Django_Enviroment\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 7 Feb 2019 13:20:49 +0000
```

Here is my views code:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Album
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import UserForm   

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "music/index.html"
    context_object_name='all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
            return Album.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):

    model=Album
    template_name='music/detail.html'

class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model=Album
    fields=['artist','album_title','genre','album_logo']

class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model=Album
    fields=['artist','album_title','genre','album_logo']

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model=Album
    success_url=reverse_lazy('music:index')

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class=UserForm
    template_name='music/registration_form.html'



  def get(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

    def post(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            #clean data
            user=form.save(commit=False)
            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()


            #return user if the data entered is correct
            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('music:index')

        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form',form})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You missed the colon after `form`

**Try this:**

`return render(request,self.template_name,{"form":form})`